# How to use Tensorflow Dataset for CNN Model Training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I wanted to feed my data using `tf.data.Dataset` class

```
from tensorflow_core.python.keras.datasets import cifar10
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = cifar10.load_data()

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_images, train_labels))
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_images, test_labels))
```

- I am doing this to use `Dataset` in my pipeline.
- Utilize other features of `Dataset` further down.

I am defining my model like this

```
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
    model.add(layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2)))
    # more layers
```

But when I call to train the model

```
model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=10, validation_data=test_dataset, callbacks=[ cp_callback])
```

I get an error

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 32, 3)

- What is really happening? How do I use `DataSet` in my Conv2D layer with input_shape=(32, 32, 3) ?

The Tensorflow tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/numpy) did not cover this scenario and I cannot find an explanation that will help me solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A batch generator should be added to your datasets with an arbitrary batch size. Based on Tensorflow's documentation [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py#L105-L1599), `batch` function:

> Combines consecutive elements of this dataset into batches.
>       The components of the resulting element will have an additional outer
>       dimension, which will be `batch_size` (or `N % batch_size` for the last
>       element if `batch_size` does not divide the number of input elements `N`
>       evenly and `drop_remainder` is `False`). If your program depends on the
>       batches having the same outer dimension, you should set the `drop_remainder`
>       argument to `True` to prevent the smaller batch from being produced.

Let say your batch size is `16`. Then:

```
my_batch_size =16
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_images, train_labels))
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_images, test_labels))
# Shapes of data are (32,32,3) here

train_dataset.batch(my_batch_size)
test_dataset.batch(my_batch_size)
# Shapes of data are (None,32,32,3) or (16,32,32,3) here
```

Then you can train your model.

Comment: Thank you very much. The tutorial that I referred to mentioned batch, but didn't mention it as a requirement and I totally got confused.